# String manipulation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on some string manipulations using javascript.I have a senario where i need to do a search in the string and remove certain words.

Here is my senario:
 When i click 'Click me' it should look for the word in the input from the string variable,
 and if matching found it should remove that word from the input.

Here is my sepecial senario, while removing the word from the input, it should remove the : and the integer value and comma (if available) which is there before the matching word.

In my example input is 1:first user,2:second user in the text box
i need the output as 2:second user

How can i achive this

```
 <input id='textinput' type='text' value='1:first user,2:second user'></input>
 <div class='click'>Click me</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".click").click(function () {
        var string = 'first user';
        $('#textinput').val().replace(/string/g, '');
    });
});
```

i have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h9D5W/

EDIT

*here my variable string contains only user names i can't append id's with user names for example 1:first user, so the exact match will not be there in the string variable.*

Comment: could you show some input & expected output examples?

Answer (score 3):

I have removed the starting digits, underscore and ending comma.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".click").click(function () {
        var string = 'first user';
        var re = new RegExp('\\d:*'+string+',*',"g");
        var text = $('#textinput').val().replace(re, '');;
        $('#textinput').val(text);

    });
});
```

**Check the demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/yKfur/1/

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript code, `string` is a variable. You'd need to initiate the `RegExp` class to generate the pattern:

Also, please refrain from using variable name like `string`. It's the name of a global object.

```
var s = 'first user';
var x = $( '#textinput' ).val().replace(new RegExp(s, 'g'), '');
// use the new variable x as you wish
```

Comment: That will leave a string like `'1:,2:second user'`, but I think the OP wants: `'2:second user'`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), You need to initialize it with string variable.

Use

```
$(".click").click(function () {
    var string = 'first user';
    var re = new RegExp(string,"g"); //initialize RegExp
    var text = $('#textinput').val().replace(re, ''); //Get replaced text
    $('#textinput').val(text);  //Reset its value      
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yKfur/)

EDIT

*here i cant use 1:first user in the variable*

```
$(".click").click(function () {
    var arr = $('#textinput').val().split(','); //Here used split method to split string ',' as deliminator 
    $('#textinput').val(arr[arr.length - 1]);        
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rCD3Q/)

Comment: I think this should be the right answer, because only in this solution the new value is set to the textfield.

Comment: this code will output 1:,2:second user. But i need to remove 1:, also

Comment: @user3791078 - `var string = '1:first user,'`

Comment: here i cant use 1:first user in the variable

Comment: is there any other way to do this?

Comment: here my variable string contains only user names i can't append id's with user names for example 1:first user, so the exact match will not be there in the string variable.

Comment: @user3791078, Then try with RobG or Nabeel Bape answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like:

```
 var text = '1:first user,2:second user,3:third user';

 var s = 'first user';

 var re = new RegExp('^\\d+:' + s + ',?|,\\d+:' + s + '\\b');

 text.replace(re, '') // '2:second user,3:third user'
```

I'm sure there's a shorter one though.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9D5W/5/)

first, i split your string into array

```
var inputArr = ($('#textinput').val()).split(',');
```

so i can check each set of words using `for` loop,

```
    for (i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {

        if (inputArr[i].indexOf(string) == -1) {
            newStr = newStr + inputArr[i] + ',';
        }
    }
```

then i set the new value using substring to eliminate the last comma appended.

```
$('#textinput').val(newStr.substring(0, newStr.length - 1));
```